# Can an iPhone device passcode be enabled in Xamarin Test Cloud?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin-test-cloud, passcode

I have an iPhone application that requires the user to have a device passcode enabled in order to use the application (for HIPAA compliance reasons).  I want to test this application on the Xamarin Test Cloud.  I've used the Xamarin Test Recorder to build a test that executes successfully on my local iPhone device (which has a passcode enabled).  When I upload the test to the Test Cloud and run it on the same iPhone device and same OS, I see my test fail because the test cloud device does not have a passcode enabled.

Is there a way to enable a passcode on a Test Cloud iPhone device?  Or a way to simulate having one enabled?

To be clear, by passcode, I mean the 4-6 number code that you would enter in order to gain access to the device after waking it from sleep (e.g. by pressing the home button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot enable the passcode on iOS devices with Xamarin Test Cloud.